# Equating nodes in prolog?

Tags: recursion, tree, prolog

I'm working on a small function which checks to see if a tree is just a reversed version of another tree.

For example,

```
  1             1
2   3    =    3   2
1                 1
```

My code is just versions of the following:

```
treeRev(leaf(Leaf1), leaf(Leaf2)) :-
    leaf(Leaf1) is leaf(Leaf2).

treeRev(node1(Leaf1, Node1), node1(Leaf2, Node2)) :-
    node1(Leaf1,treeRev(Node1)) is node1(Leaf2, treeRev(Node2)).

treeRev(node2(Leaf1, Node1, Node2), node2(Leaf2, Node3, Node4)) :- 
    node2(Leaf1, treeRev(Node1), treeRev(Node2)) is 
        node2(Leaf2, treeRev(Node4), treeRev(Node3)).
```

Where my basis is as following:

Base case is the two leaves are equal, which just returns true. If it has one node, check the leaves are equal, and call the function recursively on the node.

If it's two nodes, check the trees are equal, and then call the recursive function after having flipped the nodes from the second tree.

---

My issue is, I keep getting the bug

```
ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `leaf/1' is not a function
```

Thing is, I don't get this error when using other operations on the tree. Any advice on how to get around this? The only limitation imposed is that I can't use `=`.

I also figured that the most probable cause is that the sides of the `is` don't return the same "type", according to searches on google and stackoverflow. The way I see it though, is that shouldn't be the case here since I have almost the exact same thing on both ends.

---

Thank you for reading, and any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is/2 predicate is used for arithmetic. It calculates and assigns the value of an expression (second argument) to the variable-first argument. For example:
  `X is 1+(2*Y)/2`  where Y is already instantiated so it has a value (in order to calculate the value of the expression otherwise it throws instantiation error).

In you case you can't use is/2 since you don't want to calculate any arithmetic expression (that's why the error). What you need is unification, you need to unify a term (e.g a leaf or node) with another term by using `=`.
For example:

```
treeRev(leaf(Leaf1), leaf(Leaf2)) :-
   leaf(Leaf1) = leaf(Leaf2).

treeRev(node1(Leaf1, Node1), node1(Leaf2, Node2)) :-
    node1(Leaf1,treeRev(Node1)) = node1(Leaf2, treeRev(Node2)).

treeRev(node2(Leaf1, Node1, Node2), node2(Leaf2, Node3, Node4)) :- 
    node2(Leaf1, treeRev(Node1), treeRev(Node2)) =
        node2(Leaf2, treeRev(Node4), treeRev(Node3)).
```

By using pattern matching you could simply do:

```
treeRev(leaf(Leaf2), leaf(Leaf2)).

treeRev(node1(Leaf2, treeRev(Node2)), node1(Leaf2, Node2)).

treeRev(node2(Leaf2,Node1,Node2), node2(Leaf2, Node3, Node4)):-
          treeRev(Node1,Node4),treeRev(Node2,Node3).
```

Comment: Hi, thanks :) but what I'm trying to avoid is needing to use '='. Is there a way to get the same result without unification? I know its a wierd limitation but that's the problem's conditions.

Comment: Yes of course, I just tried t explained why is/2 failed. So you need to use some kind of unification. If you have the restriction not to use =/2 then you could do it by using pattern matching (which is also unification but it doesn't use = symbol). I will update my answer...

Comment: That's awesome man, the way you thought of it makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

> ... then call the recursive function...

Prolog predicates are not functions. Writing `node1(Leaf1,treeRev(Node1))` will not build a node with "the result of calling the `treeRev` function", as in other programming languages. Instead, Prolog predicates have extra arguments for the "result". You typically call the predicate and bind such "results" to a variable or unify it with a term.

You will need something like this for a binary node (not tested, and not following your teacher's strange and undocumented tree representation):

```
tree_mirrored(node(LeftTree, RightTree), node(RightMirrored, LeftMirrored)) :-
    tree_mirrored(LeftTree, LeftMirrored),
    tree_mirrored(RightTree, RightMirrored).
```